# While loop runs regardless of correct/incorrect input

Tags: c++

I have this program I am working on and for some reason the while loop is not running the way I intended/expected it to work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

const int size = 5;
char answer_sheet[size] = {'B','D','A','A','C'}; //'A','B','A','C','D','B','C','D','A','D','C','C','B','D','A'};
char student_answer[size];

char answer;


for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;
    while(answer != 'A' || answer != 'B' || answer != 'C' || answer != 'D')
    {
        cout << "You must enter either A, B, C, or D" << endl;
        cout << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;

    }
    student_answer[i] = answer;

}

return 0;
}
```

I am entering a char A,B,C, or D and when I enter it the correct way I go into the while loop when I am not suppose to unless I enter the char incorrectly.

I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Thanks

Comment: :) I find these titles funny. read "`<basic C++ concept>` isn't working as it should be" as "isn't working as I expect it to work"

Comment: eh my english isn't the greatest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot C and D (probably a typo):

```
while(answer != 'A' || answer != 'B' || answer != 'A' || answer != 'B')
```

Maybe you want:

```
while (answer != 'A'
       && answer != 'B'
       && answer != 'C'
       && answer != 'D')
{
}
```

Another method:

```
const std::string allowable_answers = "ABCD";
//...
while (allowable_answers.find(answer) == std::string::npos)
{
   // answer is not in the allowable set.
}
```

Comment: Yea it was a typo my bad.

Answer (score 2):

`answer != 'A' || answer != 'B'` is *always* true, for any value of `answer`.
Did you mean `&&` instead of `||`?

Answer (score 1):

The condition you're looking for is

```
while(answer != 'A' && answer != 'B' && answer != 'C' && answer != 'D')
```

The || should be && in each case, and you should also never check for 'C' or 'D'

Answer (score 0):

First, why don't you use a do/while loop instead of a while loop. Secondly, you have

```
while(answer != 'A' || answer != 'B' || answer != 'A' || answer != 'B')
{
    cout << "You must enter either A, B, C, or D" << endl;
    cout << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;

}
```

Shouldn't the program loop if A, B, C, D aren't input? You have this to loop if A, B, A, B isn't the answer.  A do/while loop will enter the loop and continue the loop if the proper answer hasn't been input